# loading multiple Imageview from url with Picasso?

Tags: android, android-layout, image-loading, picasso

I am trying to load multiple ImageView with Picasso but it loads only one ImageView. HEre is my code :

```
    public void setClassicImg(JSONArray listImg, RelativeLayout rl) throws JSONException, IOException, MalformedURLException {
    if (listImg.length() > 0)
    {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        for (int i = 0; i < listImg.length(); i++) 
        {

            ImageView downloadedImg = new ImageView(this);
                            //  downloadedImg.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(listImg.getJSONObject(i).getString("color")));
            //      new DownloadImageTask(downloadedImg).execute(listImg.getJSONObject(i).getString("http"));

            Picasso.with(this.getApplicationContext()).load(listImg.getJSONObject(i).getString("http")).into(downloadedImg);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (metrics.widthPixels * listImg.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_x")), (int) (metrics.heightPixels * listImg.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("size_y")));
            params.leftMargin = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * listImg.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_x"));
            params.topMargin = (int) (metrics.heightPixels * listImg.getJSONObject(i).getDouble("position_y"));
            downloadedImg.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            //              downloadedImg.getLayoutParams().width = BIND_ALLOW_OOM_MANAGEMENT;


            /// downloadedImg.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);
            //                  downloadedImg.setImageDrawable(animation);
            rl.addView(downloadedImg, params);
        }
    }
}
```

I am parsin a json file. The string who contains the .png or .jpg for the Image is in the String http so I get it but on the device, it shows only the first ImageView loaded, seems like if it does the loop one time.

Anybody has an idea of what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any update on it ?

Answer (score 0):

I got in the same problem, Picasso just load the first one, in my case my solution was create a custom class to handle it, so I stored the URLs in an List, and when it end loading the first I started loading the next. and to not be slow I loaded everything without target, so it cached the images.

```
@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
    //DO whatever you need with the bitmap
    urls.remove(currentUrl);
    if (urls.size() > 0) {
        currentUrl = urls.get(0);
        Picasso.with(context).load(urls.get(0)).into(this);
    }
}
```

and my method to add Urls

```
public void addUrl(String url) {
    urls.add(url);
    if (currentUrl.isEmpty()) {
        //this would be the first Url, so load directly
        currentUrl = url;
        Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(this);
    }
    else {
        //load to cache, than when loaded into the target it will get from memory
        Picasso.with(context).load(url);
    }
}
```